# which is most efficient [ & simple :p] way of parsing .pdf files ? Using Adobe API's or Perl/C?

Tags: pdf, adobe

which is most efficient way of parsing .pdf files ?
How to use/customize adobe API's. How can i parse .pdf file using Adobe API's.

Answer (score 0):

The Adobe SDK has API wrappers in several languages.